# Get area codes from area_code_list using zipcodeR

Tags: r, blob, raw, zipcoder

I'm using the `{zipcodeR}` package. My goal is to obtain an area-code-to-zipcode reference table to incorporate the rest of the data contained in output data frames from that package, to join to other data on area code.

However, the `area_code_list` column comes in a `blob` data type as per the column types. I'm not familiar with this data type and don't know how to extract it. Neither the package vignettes nor documentation seem to point to any helper functions for this task. Looking at `str()`, it seems the underlying type is `raw`.

Ideally, I'd have one row per zipcode-area code combo as my final output. I appreciate any help.

```
search_state("CA") %>% 
  filter(zipcode %in% c("90201", "90210")) %>% 
  select(zipcode, area_code_list)

# Current output
# # A tibble: 2 × 2
# zipcode area_code_list
# <chr>           <blob>
# 90201       <raw 15 B>
# 90210       <raw 26 B>

# Ideal output
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
# zipcode area_code_list
# <chr>           <chr>
# 90201           323
# 90210           310
# 90210           424
```

Comment: I don't have that package, but have you tried applying the `rawToChar` function? It might be as simple as `mutate(area_code = sapply(area_code_list, rawToChar))` (or that might just explode due to something else).

Comment: @r2evans in this case that causes an error due to nul in the string. For example, `[1] 78 9c 8b 56 32 36 32 56 8a 05 00 06 51 01 95`. Even after removing them it still does not convert (it produces `"x\x9c\x8bV262V\x8a\005\006Q\001\x95"` in that example)

Comment: I didn't find much about working with blob types in R nor converting raw types, so I've reached out to the package author directly. I'll be sure to share anything I receive here.

Comment: Another source for the data is from: https://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/zip-code-database/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zipcodeR` seems to get its ZCTA database from this [US Zipcode Project](https://github.com/MacHu-GWU/uszipcode-project). Looking around at the project's [python package internals](https://github.com/MacHu-GWU/uszipcode-project/blob/21242cad7cbb7eaf73235086b89499bd90c36531/uszipcode/model.py#L49C34-L49C34), the `area_code_list` is typed as a `CompressedJSONType` in that python code.

I guessed, but it looks like it was compressed with Gzip. We can verify this using `jsonlite` to parse the column:

```r
zipcodeR::search_state("CA") %>% 
  dplyr::filter(zipcode %in% c("90201", "90210")) %>% 
  dplyr::select(zipcode, area_code_list) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(area_code_list = sapply(area_code_list, jsonlite::parse_gzjson_raw)) %>%
  tidyr::unnest_longer(col = area_code_list)

#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   zipcode area_code_list
#>   <chr>   <chr>         
#> 1 90201   323           
#> 2 90210   310           
#> 3 90210   323           
#> 4 90210   424
```